# ResourceDictionary doesn´t find another ResourceDictionary

Tags: xaml, resourcedictionary

i´ll create a simple Theme for some Controls. My problem is now to get access from the 1st ResourceDictionary to the 2nd ResourceDictionary.

Example: ResourceDictionary1 (**DicColors**) include the colors and the 2nd ResourceDictionary (**DicThemeColor**) need the color from **DicColors** to build SolidColorBrush:

**DicColors**

```
<Color x:Key="Color_System_Green">##8ec760</Color>
<Color x:Key="Color_System_Blue">#53baf2</Color>   
<Color x:Key="Color_System_Orange">#ff9a1e</Color>
```

**DicThemeColor**

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="{StaticResource Color_System_Green}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background Color="{StaticResource Color_System_Blue}"/>    
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="{StaticResource Color_System_Orange}"/>
```

The goal is, to define the colors in an single ResourceDictionary, that other ResourceDictionaries can use this colors from this. My problem is now, that i doesn´t have an access from **DicThemeColor** to **DicColors**

Example: I will change the background. Here a snippet from the default-template of a button.
In the App.xaml i merged the ResourceDictionaries.

```
   <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/TestApp;component/Styles/Colors/DicColors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/TestApp;component/Styles/Controls/DicThemeColor.xaml" />             
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Here now the default-template of a button. I changed only the background. You can see here the changes in the last row.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp.Styles.Controls">
    <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="{DynamicResource Color.Button.Static.Background}"/>
```

When i use this style for a button, i get a white background instead green. I don´t why.

Hope you can help me.

regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the references to the two resource dictionaries to read:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styles/Colors/DicColors.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styles/Controls/DicThemeColor.xaml" />
```

Not knowing your folder structure, you may need to adjust this a bit.

Comment: Hi. Solution/Styles/Colors and Solution/Styles/Controls/